# Get folder script ran from in PHP

Tags: php, command-line

I use PHP for command line utility scripting.  I need to be able to know what directory the user ran the script from.  I tried getcwd() and **DIR**, but they return the path to the actual .PHP file not the directory I am in when I run them.  My solution was to launch my scripts via a batch file, doing like php p:\utils\scripts\um.php "%CD%" %1 %2 %3, etc.

I was hoping there was a better way, some sort of PHP constant or function that would tell me this?  Thanks!

Comment: Would `PWD` help you?

Comment: Ah sorry, should have mentioned I was on Windows.